# lubuntu-desktop package interfered with the graphics for my Ubuntu desktop

Tags: graphics, lubuntu

I installed the lubuntu-desktop package with all it's dependencies recently and since then the graphics of my other desktops, Ubuntu, 2d ubuntu and gnome-shell are ruined. By ruined I mean I don't know what happened. It' not just the compositing, compiz is still running and restarting it does nothing.

Another thing I noticed is the lubuntu splash screen shows up during boot and shutdown whether I was in a lubuntu session or not.

Sorry for such little info. any ideas?

32bit 11.10

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure how these things got sorted together but heres how I fixed it.

```
-Open ccsm
--reset default profile to default settings. under advanced section
---enable jpeg support in image handeling
---turn wallpaper plugin on
----choose image for wallpaper
```

thats all.